# sess_destroy() No funciona en codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

Excelente noche, espero me puedan ayudar, cuando mando a llamar mi función para destruir la sesión, esta no es destruida y esta sigue activa si trato de ingresar por la URL.

mi controlador es el siguiente, para iniciar y por supuesto acá esta la función para poder destruir la sesión

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class login extends CI_Controller {
public function __constuct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index(){
    if($this->session->userdata('username')){
        redirect('admin');
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password'])){
        $this->load->model('usuario_model');
        if($this->usuario_model->login($_POST['username'],md5($_POST['password']))){
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$_POST['username']);
            redirect('admin');
        }else{
            redirect('login');
        }
    }   
    $this->load->view('login');
}
public function logout(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();        
    redirect('login');
}
}
```

mando a traer el función desde mi vista de la siguiente manera:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="<?=site_url('login/logout') ?>">Salir</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: fíjate si no es que el cache te está jugando en contra https://stackoverflow.com/a/9044464/1423096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('login')) {
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

Valida si la `session` esta abierta desde el constructor de cada controlador.

Con esta validación si el usuario no esta con la `session` abierta hara un `redirect` al inicio, al menos yo lo solucioné de esta forma, saludos.